# How to link Android Studio with PhpmyAdmin

Tags: android-studio, phpmyadmin

I am new to Android Studio and Pho programming. 
I am making a Login/Register App on Android Studio and want to link it with database I created on PhpMyAdmin. I read around and many suggest the use of WAMP server to do so.
Can I connect to phpMyAdmin without WAMP server. I installed manually php, mysql, and Apache24. If this is possible, which URL, I have to use. Also, where I need to put my pfp.files.
Thanks

Comment: If you already installed PHP, MySQL, and Apache manually there is no point to installing WAMP (which includes **A**pache, **M**ySQL, and **P**HP) -- doing so will cause them to conflict with each other and cause you more trouble. Pick one or the other; pre-packaged distribution kid like WAMP or rolling your own as you've already done.

Answer (score 1):

You dont connect to Phpmyadmin. Phpmyadmin is just a gui for mysql. You are going to have to write a backend for your application in php for example and send request to that.

Comment: I wrote two php files to read from the mysql database and write to it, but still have no idea how to deal with them. So, could you provide me a way to connect to mysql database which I created using phpMyAdmin without the need for WAMP server. Which request URl should I use ? where I need to place the php files (to SELECT / INSERT into the database). Thanks